# Is it possible to add a decorator to returned function?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to achieve the following?

```
foo () {
    @decorator
    return () => {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try calling the decorator function on the return value? Like `return decorator(() => {});`?

Comment: No. Decorators are only for classes as written in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html): "With the introduction of **Classes** in TypeScript and ES6, there now exist certain scenarios that require additional features to support annotating or modifying **classes** and **class** members. Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for **class** declarations and members."

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't decorate expression.

But wrapping returned function will do what you want to get

```
foo () {
    return decorator(() => {
    });
}
```